# Java, get full path of file and removing filename

Tags: java, file, path, apache-commons

I'm trying to get the directory path to a file. The issue I am having is getting the last `\` or `/` of the directory. As this code is supposed to work on all operating systems, I can't seem to find any solution for this. Any help is appreciated.

**My code so far:**

```
System.out.print("Enter dir: ");
String path = kb.nextLine();
File pathes = new File(path);
String path2 = pathes.getParent();
path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
System.out.println("PATH: " + path);
System.out.println("PATH2: "+path2);
```

**My output is:**

```
PATH: C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\
PATH2: C:\Users\User\Desktop\test
```

This is just test code and not the real code I'm working on.

**EDIT**
What I'm trying to get is

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\
```

from

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\test.txt
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but `Paths.get(kb.nextLine()).toAbsolutePath().getParent()` will likely work for you.

Comment: Instead of searching for \\ you can search for FileSystem.getSeparator() to get it platform independent

Comment: @explv your code will only  give me C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\test.txt

Comment: @Mena What im trying to get is C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\ from C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\test.txt

Comment: @Izban why do you need the trailing slash? To get the path without the slash you can do: `pathes.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()` if you really want the slash then `pathes.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator`

Comment: @explv It's needed for saving a file a specific way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the absolute path to the parent directory you can do:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\test.txt");
String path = f.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(path);
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test
```

If you **really** want the trailing slash, then you can just append `File.separator`:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\test.txt ");
String path = f.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
System.out.println(path);
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\
```

Comment: I need to get pathes.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator into a string. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Izban it is a `String`?

Comment: Yeah, looks like i've missed adding that info to the original question. So what i need to do is add pathes.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator into a string/file/path variable.

Comment: @Izban no i'm saying my answer stores the path in a String: `String path = pathes.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;`

Comment: My bad! I accidentally added () at the end of File.separator. Thank you for the help, highly appreciated!